# Docker Compose: Bind for 0.0.0.0:3307 failed: port is already allocated

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a Spring Boot that that connects to a MySQL DB. I'm trying to Dockerize it and create a `docker-compose.yml` that stands up a MySQL container and then stands up a Dockerized version of my Spring Boot app that can talk to it.

My project looks like this:

```
myapp/
  src/
    main/
      java/
        <All the Java code here>
      resources/
        application.yml
  build/
    libs/
      myapp.jar
  Dockerfile
  .env
  docker-compose.yml
```

When I run `./gradlew clean bootJar` it builds a `build/libs/myapp.jar`.

My `.env` file:

```
MAIN_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
MAIN_DB_PORT=3307
MAIN_DB_DOCKER_PORT=3306
MAIN_DB_USERNAME=root
MAIN_DB_PASSWORD=123456
MAIN_DB_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
MAIN_DB_DATABASE=myapp_db

SERVER_PORT=9200
WS_PORT=9200
WS_DOCKER_PORT=9201
```

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:11

RUN mkdir /opt/app

COPY app/build/libs/myapp.jar myapp

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","myapp"]
```

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  myapp_db:
    image: mysql:8.0.32
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MAIN_DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=$MAIN_DB_DATABASE
      - MYSQL_CHARSET=utf8mb4
      - MYSQL_COLLATION=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
      - MYSQL_ENGINE=InnoDB
    ports:
      - $MAIN_DB_PORT:$MAIN_DB_DOCKER_PORT
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
  myapp:
    depends_on:
      - myapp_db
    build: .
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - $WS_PORT:$WS_DOCKER_PORT
      - $MAIN_DB_PORT:$MAIN_DB_DOCKER_PORT
volumes:
  db:
```

When I run `./gradlew clean bootJar && docker-compose --env-file .env up -d` I see my Docker image get built but when it starts up I get:

```
WARNING: Image for service myapp was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating myapp_myapp_db_1         ... done
Creating myapp_myapp_db_1         ... 
Creating myapp_myapp_db_1         ... error

ERROR: for myapp_myapp_db_1 Cannot start service myapp: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint myapp_myapp_db_1 (33899c0810d03db26ef7b48e67328ea9eb4e0f75cebc0201e667db72ce21d7ba): Bind for 0.0.0.0:3307 failed: port is already allocated

ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

**Can anyone spot where I'm going awry?**

Comment: It's saying something else is listening on port defined by `MAIN_DB_PORT`. Check what that is and either shut it down or choose another port.

Comment: Oh, I see now - you don't need to map the db port like they should share the same network so you should not need to expose it at all.

Comment: Thanks @fredrik, could you tell me exactly what changes I need to make, and to which file?

Comment: I'd just remove the port definitions for the database. Your app can use `myapp_db` as hostname for the database.

Comment: Thanks, so you're saying, in the **docker-compose.yml` file, take `ports:\ - $MAIN_DB_PORT:$MAIN_DB_DOCKER_PORT` out from the `myapp_db` service definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to publish the same ports twice

```yaml
services:
  myapp_db:
    ports:
      - $MAIN_DB_PORT:$MAIN_DB_DOCKER_PORT
  myapp:
    ports:
      - $MAIN_DB_PORT:$MAIN_DB_DOCKER_PORT
```

Having the same port number on the left-hand side of two `ports:` lines will cause the "port is already allocated" error you see.  However, the `ports:` declaration routes network connections to a specific container; since `myapp` isn't running a database, it doesn't need that `ports:` line at all.

(The second `ports:` number is a fixed value for whatever image you're running; for MySQL, it will *always* be 3306.  I wouldn't bother including this in a `.env` file.  Also consider that `ports:` are not used or required for connections between containers and you may not need `ports:` for your database at all.)

You should delete the `MAIN_DB_PORT` line for your application, but make sure to leave the line that publishes your application's port.

```yaml
services:
  myapp_db:
    ports:
      - $MAIN_DB_PORT:3306  # optional
  myapp:
    ports:
      - $WS_PORT:9201       # probably required
#     - $MAIN_DB_PORT:3306  # <-- delete this one, causes the error
```